# Reciting Shomer Israel W/short Avinu Malkeinu at end before Va'anachnu lo neida only on fast days?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tachanun, selichot

During Weekdays shacharis tachanun end of tefillah, is Shomer israel/Avinu malkeinu at end before Va'anachnu lo neida only recited on tzom gedalia and other public fasts ? or do you recite it during weekdays as well?

I usually just now recite Vidui/Tehillim 6,and jump to va'anachnu lo neida before ashrei-aleinu. am i supposed to be reciting shomer israel/avinu malkeinu at end also ?

In the Alter rebbe's Tehillas HaShem, how come he included a short daily version of Avinu Malkeinu(n refers to longer version page 454 for between RH v'YK) between Tehillim 25 and va'anachnu lo neida? Why the short version without shomer israel?

Comment: They're separate pieces. Shomer Yisrael is said on Mondays and Thurdays at the end of long tachanun. Avinu Malkeinu is said before Vaanachnu after every tachanun.

Comment: Ohhh ok, because at the end of Shomer israel, it ends with a brief avinu malkeinu before va'anachnu lo neida. Just recite that bit at end but not shomer israel ? The short avinu malkeinu for weekday Mincha from Tehillas HaShem is direct without shomer israel, but shacharis it seems attached to end of shomer israel.

Comment: It's the same as mincha, except on Monday & Thursday.

Comment: Ashaynem dank for your time shmosel. very much appreciated .

Comment: The Magen Avraham ([685](https://www.sefaria.org/Magen_Avraham.685.1) echoing the Levush) notes that some have the custom to establish fast days in the winter ("Shovevim Tat") and they even say Shomer Yisrael on those days (meaning they treat them as bona fide public fasts). MA and Levush are pretty standard (eastern) Ashkenazi halachic voices.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!